# Alert Box with form and one input text

Tags: javascript

I want to open an alert box  (Javascript) with one input text, then on user click is submit to another page, its like a form with one input text, all the examples that given are modals examples, i just need an alertbox.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can use the DOM [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.prompt) method:

```
var result = prompt("Enter a value");
```

Comment: its like to put <form method=post action=test.php><input type=text..><input type=submit> in alert box

Comment: @OfirAttia - Then no, you can't do that with a native control. You'll have to use one of the thousands of existing modal/lightbox scripts, or write your own.

Comment: ok.. thanks thought its possible with simple alertbox

Comment: you will have to build a custom layout or form for this using scripts and write your own and post the code if possible for future users thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use prompt for getting user input

```
var retVal = prompt("Enter your name : ", "your name here");
document.getElementById(formId).submit();
```

this variable you can access and redirect accordingly

You can store the value of prompt in any control within the form which you can access on the submitted page after the page is submitted.

fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ze3rX/

Comment: i guess i cant submit this to another page..right?

Comment: You can store the value of prompt in any control within the form which you can access on the submitted page.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it on your own here is a link where you can have a look at different types of pop up box using javascript [popup box](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

Comment: checked this,see the comment to James

Answer (score 1):

You can do a prompt

```
name = prompt('Please enter your name');
```

and then

```
window.location = "http://yourdomain.com/yourscript.php?name="+name;
```

Now what you're doing is sending the name that the user enters to your script using the GET method.

You will obviously have to do a bit of validation and sanitization, but that's how GET basically works. If you want to POST the data entered, then look into [AJAX (XmlHttpRequests)](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php) and send the variables/params to the script URL of your choice.